# OO Design - Entity class depends on Core class

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I have a `class` called `VStateManager` in `Entity`. In my `Core` I have a `class` called `VFactory`. There is a one to one mapping between `VState` (which is on object created by VStateManager) and `V` (an object created by VFactory)

The `class VFactory` implements the following interface

```
public interface ISensorUpdate
{
        void StartVSensors(VId Id, VType Type, IVSensorHandlers Handlers);
        void StopVSensors(VId Id);
}
```

The creation of `VState` object by class `VStateManage`r is driven by a Network event. However when the `VState` object is created the corresponding `V` object should be created by `VFactory`
However as I mentioned `VStateManager` is a part of `Entity` and `VFactory` is a part of `Core`.

`VStateManager` cannot depend on `VFactory` directly. What is a good design to get around this problem.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you have a good design to start with, at least, it's unclear...  I find it super odd that VFactory implements ISensorUpdate,

Comment: Your question sounds like an IQ test (too abstract). Please change it so it looks more like a problem statement (with a business case).

Comment: Could you write a scheme of inheritance? UML diagram would be perfect. It's unclear what you are asking.